# MySQL loses connection after running stored procedure a second time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

A very bizarre issue cropped up in our MySQL RDS instance recently, and I'm having a tough time pinning down the root cause of the connection loss. We have roughly ~100 stored procedures in production, all of which previously ran without issue. Recently I noticed that some of our stored procedures, after having run successfully on their first invocation, lead to MySQL losing connection following the very next invocation of that same stored procedure (error below):

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Note: When I copy-paste and run the stored procedure as a standalone query, I can run multiple times without issue and am returned the expected results.

I pulled the following logs from AWS for this RDS instance (scrubbed IP address):

```
2021-07-19T15:22:05.982852Z 14 [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address 'X.X.X.X' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
15:24:01 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x2adff8aa1000
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 2adff72facc0 thread_stack 0x40000
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x2e) [0x205b11e]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x2eb) [0x10aa40b]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100) [0x2adff7b83100]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37) [0x2adff82dd5f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x2adff82dece8]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+0x125) [0x2b47425]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())+0x6) [0x2ab4bd6]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0x2ab4c21]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0x2ab66cf]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(is_rollup_group_wrapper(Item*)+0x15) [0xf35d65]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0xf360cd]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(WalkAndReplace(THD*, Item*, std::function<ReplaceResult (Item*, Item*, unsigned int)> const&)+0x222) [0xfb5882]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(change_to_use_tmp_fields_except_sums(mem_root_deque<Item*>*, THD*, SELECT_LEX*, Bounds_checked_array<Item*>, mem_root_deque<Item*>*)+0x5f6) [0xf3d5d6]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(JOIN::make_tmp_tables_info()+0x1785) [0xfd24f5]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(JOIN::optimize()+0x2e54) [0xf71b84]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0xa7) [0xfcc2e7]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x6b) [0x1036ffb]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(TABLE_LIST::optimize_derived(THD*)+0x40) [0x13eea20]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(JOIN::optimize()+0x44c) [0xf6f17c]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX::optimize(THD*)+0xa7) [0xfcc2e7]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(SELECT_LEX_UNIT::optimize(THD*, TABLE*, bool)+0x6b) [0x1036ffb]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute_inner(THD*)+0x2e) [0xfcad6e]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x560) [0xfd4b10]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xa7e) [0xf7957e]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(sp_instr_stmt::exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*)+0x51) [0xef81d1]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::reset_lex_and_exec_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0x16c) [0xefa04c]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(sp_lex_instr::validate_lex_and_execute_core(THD*, unsigned int*, bool)+0xcf) [0xefafcf]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(sp_instr_stmt::execute(THD*, unsigned int*)+0xc3) [0xefc7c3]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(sp_head::execute(THD*, bool)+0x3be) [0xef164e]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(sp_head::execute_procedure(THD*, mem_root_deque<Item*>*)+0x7b3) [0xef4843]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_call::execute_inner(THD*)+0x136) [0x13e40e6]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x560) [0xfd4b10]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0xa7e) [0xf7957e]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(dispatch_sql_command(THD*, Parser_state*)+0x3cc) [0xf7d26c]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x14c4) [0xf7ec34]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x1ef) [0xf8070f]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0x109ba80]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld() [0x25e00cf]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5) [0x2adff7b7bdc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x2adff839ec9d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (2ae094ac99e8): WITH roster_players AS ( SELECT p.player_id FROM players p JOIN bridge_player b ON p.player_id = b.player_id WHERE ((b.player_id = NAME_CONST('id',144345) AND NAME_CONST('player_flag',0)) OR NOT NAME_CONST('player_flag',0)) AND ((team_id = NAME_CONST('id',144345) AND NAME_CONST('team_flag',1)) OR NOT NAME_CONST('team_flag',1)) AND season_id = NAME_CONST('roster_season',13)), player_games AS ( SELECT DISTINCT b.game_id FROM batters b JOIN games g ON b.game_id = g.game_id JOIN roster_players rp ON b.batter_id = rp.player_id WHERE NAME_CONST('analysis_season',13) = 0 OR YEAR(game_date) = 2020) SELECT IFNULL(totals.batter_id, 0) AS batter_id, bip_location, IF(bip_location > 9, bip_of, bip_if) AS bip, ROUND(zone_cnt / IF(bip_location > 0 AND bip_location < 10, bip_if, bip_of) * 100, 2) AS zone_pct, hrs FROM (SELECT b.batter_id, bip_location, COUNT(*) AS zone_cnt,
Connection ID (thread ID): 13
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

There may be something glaring here that I'm just overlooking, but any direction or things to test would be much appreciated.

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
    IN id INT(11)
)
BEGIN

WITH roster_players AS (
    SELECT p.player_id FROM players p
    JOIN bridge_player b ON p.player_id = b.player_id
    WHERE b.player_id = id),
        
player_games AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT b.game_id
    FROM batters b JOIN games g ON b.game_id = g.game_id
    JOIN roster_players rp ON b.batter_id = rp.player_id)

SELECT 
    b.batter_id,
        bip_location,
        COUNT(*) AS zone_cnt
FROM
   batters b
JOIN player_games g ON b.game_id = g.game_id
JOIN roster_players rp ON b.batter_id = rp.player_id
GROUP BY bip_location , b.batter_id WITH ROLLUP;

END
```

Comment: File a bug report with Amazon and MySQL.  You will need to provide the Stored Proc and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I've slowly narrowed it down to a `WITH ROLLUP` clause to my `GROUP BY`. So bizarre...still working on a solution.

Comment: We might be able to discuss further if we could see the query and the SP.

Comment: Added SP to my post, without that final `WITH ROLLUP` clause, the issue disappears

Comment: You should file a bug report with AWS, then you should answer your own question so others can find the answer

Comment: This would not be the first bug related to GROUP BY handling in MySQL 8.0 (appears 8.0 since you have CTEs in the query). My team ran into bug #32324234 that's fixed in 8.0.26 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-26.html).

Comment: That could very well have been the problem, I've since rewritten our SP's in an optimization effort that seems to have resolved the issue. I'll read through those release notes, appreciate your comment.